# lombok AST transformations without annotations

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, lombok

Is it possible to switch `Integer` type declarations to `int` or add `final` to local variables using lombok without annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to extend the custom handler from JavacASTAdapter or EclipseASTAdapter.

HandleVal from standard lombok distribution can be used as a reference implementation.

Here is the code for example transformations above:

```
@ProviderFor(JavacASTVisitor.class)
public class SomeHandler extends JavacASTAdapter
{
  @Override
  public void visitLocal(JavacNode localNode, JCTree.JCVariableDecl local)
  {
    local.mods.flags |= Flags.FINAL;

    if (local.vartype.toString().equals("int"))
      local.vartype = localNode.getTreeMaker().Ident(localNode.toName("Integer"));

    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you mean with the Integer to int switching, but you can declare a final local variable using:

```
val name = "My Name";
```

This will create a local final String variable called `name`.

Disclosure: I am one of the Project Lombok authors.

Comment: int switching is just an example. The need is to search and rewrite code that corresponds to some signatures and which is not marked by annotations.